# Sending 'large' amount of data cross-origin

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain, html2canvas

I have a javascript bookmarklet which creates a screenshot of an element and saves it as a base64 encoded string.

Now, I need to send that image/string to my own server to save it. Only problem is that it's 6000+ characters long, or about 61 KB, making it unrealistic to `GET` it back to my server.

Is there some sort of external service that would somehow retrieve it back on my server? How can I send this image to my server?

Comment: Would enabling CORS on your server (http://enable-cors.org/) and using POST be an option for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use POST.

Option A.) Use JavaScript to create a form, and post the data. If you do not want the page location to change, set `target` of the form to a hidden iframe.

If you need to get a response back from your server after the post, add a unique key to the form that you post, like `<input type="hidden" name="key" value="...">` and then after the post is done use JSONP to get the response, like `http://yourserver.com/donepost.php?key=...`. Since you can't be sure that the post will complete before the JSONP call is made, you'll need to keep rechecking the server until a valid response is available or it times out.

Option B.) Post using AJAX. Set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on your server to allow this.